# See :hover state in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, hover, google-chrome-devtools

I want to see the `:hover` style for an anchor I'm hovering on in **Chrome**. In **Firebug**, there's a style dropdown that allows me to select different states for an element.

> I can't seem to find anything similar in Chrome. Am I missing something?

Comment: Good question 'cos I was looking for how to edit hover style in Firebug - see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389245/how-do-i-inspect-css-pseudo-classes-with-firebug

Comment: I know it's not a complete/perfect solution to the problem, but couldn't find a solution in the answers that would work for mouseover events. Using Safari allows you to hover while using browser tools. Hence, just for this problem, consider using another browser.

Answer (score 1443, accepted):

Now you can see both the pseudo-class rules and force them on elements.

To see the rules like `:hover` in the Styles pane click the small `:hov` text in the top right.

[image: Toggle element state]

To force an element into `:hover` state, right click it and select `:hover`.

[image: Force element state]

Additional tips on the [elements panel](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/shortcuts#elements-panel) in [Chrome Developer Tools Shortcuts](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/shortcuts).

Comment: Not sure when this changed, but you can now right click -> force element state (from the elements pane) on other elements (not just `<a>` elements) now.

Comment: This works for CSS :hover changes, but not if you make changes onhover using JS.

Comment: Here's a quick video I threw together demonstrating the :hover state in Chrome 59 if it helps anyone https://youtu.be/Bklz3lGTFi8

Comment: Any1 else having trouble that the 'force element state' buttons are greyed out and not clickable?

Answer (score 61):

This was a bit tricky, but here it goes :

- Right-click the element, but DON'T move your mouse pointer away from the element 
  – *keep the mouse in hover state*.
- Choose **Inspect** via the keyboard: hit the up arrow (), then the Enter key (<kbd>↵</kbd>).
- If needed, use the up/down arrow to find the correct HTML element in the developer tools.
- Look in the developer tools under matched Rules/Styles. 
  The top CSS selector should be of `:hover` type.

Answer (score 37):

I wanted to see the hover state on my Bootstrap tooltips. Forcing the the `:hover` state in Chrome dev Tools did not create the required output, yet triggering the `mouseenter` event via console did the trick in Chrome. If jQuery exists on the page you can run:

```
$('.YOUR-TOOL-TIP-CLASS').trigger('mouseenter');
```

[image: Forcing hover or mouseenter for Bootstrap Tooltips]

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).trigger is not a function`

Comment: @alansiqueira27 Then the site has no jQuery included (it becomes less and less common for it to be there). You have to use plain old javascript. Maybe that will work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50587874/457268

Answer (score 29):

There are several ways to see **HOVER STATE** styles in Chrome Developer Tools.

**Method 01**

[image]

**Method 02**

[image]

**With Firefox Default Developer Toll**

[image]

**With Firebug**

[image]

Answer (score 9):

In case it helps, this seems to be easier in the latest Chrome (47.0.2526.106):

Inspect element and then click on the three white dots in the left gutter:
[image: click on the three white dots]

Then choose the desired element state from this dropdown:
[image: this dropdown]

Comment: duplicate of most of the other posts here.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a way to do this. I submitted **[a feature request](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67871)**. If there is a way, the developers at Google will surly point it out and I will edit my answer. If not, we will have to wait and watch. (you can star the issue to vote for it)

---

> [Comment 1 by Chrome project member](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67871#c1): In 10.0.620.0, the Styles panel shows the :hover styles for the selected element but not :active.

---

(as of this post) Current [Stable channel](http://www.google.com/chrome?platform=win) version is 8.0.552.224.

You can replace your [Stable channel](http://www.google.com/chrome?platform=win) installation of Google Chrome with the [Beta channel](http://www.google.com/intl/en/landing/chrome/beta/) or the [Dev channel](http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?extra=devchannel) (See [Early Access Release Channels](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel)).

You can also install a [secondary installation of chrome that is even more up to date than the Dev channel](http://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs).

> ... The Canary build is updated even more frequently than the Dev channel and is not tested before being released.  Because the Canary build may at times be unusable, it cannot be set as your default browser and may be installed in addition to any of the above channels of Google Chrome. ...

Comment: Great investigation. I'm rocking the latest dev build (10.0.612.3) so I'll just wait a bit and hopefully I'll see the :hover goodness!

Answer (score 4):

I know that what I do is quite the workaround, however it works perfectly and that is the way I do it everytime.

[image: Undock Chrome Developer Tools]

Then, proceed like this:

- First make sure Chrome Developer Tools is undocked.
- Then, just move any side of the Dev Tools window to the middle of the element you want to inspect while hovered.

[image: Hover on element]

- Finally, hover the element, right click and inspect element, move your mouse into the Dev Tools window and you will be able to play with your element:hover css.

Cheers!

Comment: Going to add a comment so I can find this again, because I know I'm going to need it! Especially important for unpredictable third party UI plugins.

Answer (score 3):

I was debugging a menu `hover` state with Chrome and did this to be able to see the hover state code:

In the `Elements` panel click over `Toggle Element state` button and select `:hover`.

In the `Scripts` panel go to `Event Listeners Breakpoints` in the right bottom section and select `Mouse -> mouseup`.

Now inspect the Menu and select the box you want. When you release the mouse button it should stop and show you the selected element hover state in the `Elements` panel (look at the `Styles` section).

Answer (score 3):

Changing to **hover** status in Chrome is pretty easy, just follow these steps below:

1) **Right click** in your page and select inspect

[image]

2) Select the element you like to have inspect in the **DOM**

[image]

3) Select the pin icon  [image]  (Toggle Element State)

4) Then tick the **hover**

[image]

Now you can see the hover state of the selected **DOM** in the browser!

Answer (score 3):

For me in order to debug this tooltip i click on toggle device toolbar to switch to mobile view and then click on div that has the hover effect, you can also click on focus-visible to see the spacing between the div and tooltip, hope this will help.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to trigger the `MouseEvent` on elements using JS. Here is how to do it for `hover`.

1. Inspect the element using right click.
2. Copy JS path like this [image]
3. Open console in Sources Chrome DevTools by pressing "Esc" key.
4. Then paste the copied path and append it with `.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseover', { 'bubbles': true }));` like this: [image]
5. Press enter and then you can interact with any DOM changes happening after hover state.

Comment: For some reason doesn't work for me, nothing happens even though I get "true" returned when calling dispatchEvent in the Console :D

Answer (score 1):

I think this is no longer an issue in Chrome but just in case. I wrote this jQuery [script](https://gist.github.com/davidmontoyago/7028854) to inspect the DOM when I move around with the TAB key.

If changed to use 'mouseover', would look like this:

```
$("body *").on('mouseover', function(event) {       
    console.log(event.target);      
    inspect(event.target);
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

You can easily modify it to remove the event handler whenever you click or do something on an element you want to stop at.

Comment: i try but `window.inspect is not a function` , and imposible to import utils !

Answer (score 1):

I could see the style by following below steps suggested by Babiker - 
"Right-click element, but DON'T move your mouse pointer away from the element, keep it in hover state. Choose inspect element via keyboard, as in hit up arrow and then Enter key."

For changing style follow above steps and then -
Change your browser tab by pressing ctrl + TAB on the keyboard.
Then click back on the tab you want to debug. Your hover screen will still be there. Now carefully take your mouse to developer tool area.

Comment: You do not need to keep your mouse in hover state

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I want to dubug bootstrap tooltip.  But the methods above not work for me.  I guess bootstrap implemented this by something like mouse in/out event.

Anyway, when I hover on a button, it will generate a brother html element below the button, so I select the button's parent element in "Elements" tab of "Developer tools" window, hover the button, and "Ctrl + C", then I can paste the source code which contains the generated code. Last find the generated code, and add it to the source code by "Edit as HTML" in "Elements" tab.

Hope it can help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible that the code can be hidden in the database and there is no actual file containing it.  A client of mine has the "Travelify" theme by Colorlib and some of the options from the WP admin GUI write directly to the DB and the DB generates the css code on the fly - I can see the css in html source but nowhere in any actual files.  This drove me crazy and took me awhile to figure out.  There's a great DB search tool for WP called "Search and Replace" by Inpsyde GmbH that I have found to be invaluable.  Be careful with it of course!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [@k0pernikus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27623294/19737860) answer above, if you don't have `jQuery`:

1. Grab the element selector

[image: grab element selector]

2. Open the `Console`
3. Select the element with `$('<paste_selector_here>')`
4. Trigger a `mouseenter` event with `dispatchEvent`

```js
     $('<paste_selector_here>').dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseenter'))
```

[image: selector-and-dispatch-event]

Then in my case, with a tooltip, the tooltip will be added to the DOM as if your mouse was hovered over it, allowing you to see the styles that are applied while in the `:hover` state.

[image: mouse-hover-tooltip-added-to-DOM]