# Bootstrap Button Pressed State

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got an issue with my buttons and I don't know where the CSS is. If you look on my site, http://www.gnarlydigital.com/services, you'll see a button with 'Start your project>>'. When you hover over the button, the button looks like it's been pressed. If you click and hold then the button gains an inner shaddow and the border at the bottom appears again.

How can I fix it so that the hover and the press and hold states are the same?

Thank you.

Comment: i would start with looking at the pseudo states active and hover and see if you can spot anything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [See :hover state in Chrome Developer Tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515124/see-hover-state-in-chrome-developer-tools)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Richlewis, I've spotted it. One of the problems was seeing the active state, but this post answers it perfectly. 
[See :hover state in Chrome Developer Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515124/see-hover-state-in-chrome-developer-tools)