# Sub-Navigation Dropdown deactivates on mouse-out

Tags: css

I have a menu and a submenu. The submenu needs to display on mouseover, but needs to display below the colored area. When I mouseout of Item 3, the submenu disappears.

I understand why it is disappearing and I am wondering if there is a way make this work. Margin and Padding didn't seem to work on the ul li css.

http://jsfiddle.net/G4dss/

```
<div id="bg">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="first leaf">Item 1</li>
      <li class="leaf">Item 2</li>
      <li class="expanded">Item 3
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="leaf">Sub-item 1</li>
          <li class="leaf">Sub-item 2</li>
          <li class="leaf">Sub-item 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="leaf last">Last item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#bg {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
}

ul {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
}

ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Before you throw in the towel on this, please note that what you describe is achievable using solely CSS. Just in case my answer was lost below the currently highest-voted one, I ask that you review my solution one last time. I'd be happy to help if it still does not satisfy your requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you positioned the drop down too far down, you can achieve the same effect by using `padding-top` and lowering the `top`, heres a [**working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/icodeforlove/G4dss/1/)

```
ul li ul {
  top: 20px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

If you are not familiar with [chrome dev tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515124/see-hover-state-in-chrome-developer-tools) it sometimes helps to just add borders on your elements when you have issues [**like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/icodeforlove/G4dss/2/)

Comment: OK, i added som bg colors... the PSD design came over with the submenu appearing OVER the green BG, adding the padding-top creates too much negative blue space... but any other way causes the deactivation of the submenu:  http://jsfiddle.net/G4dss/8/

Comment: What you want to do is very hard without javascript. but if you can get away with solid colors, try using a border instead http://jsfiddle.net/icodeforlove/G4dss/9/

Comment: Can that border be transparent? as in, completely transparent?

Comment: Oh, and I agree, extremely hard to do... just needed to verify so I can tell the client :)

Comment: @ClaytonDaniels heres a way with psuedo elements http://jsfiddle.net/icodeforlove/G4dss/10, which would be fine depending on browser requirements. I would try to stay away from adding extra elements to the DOM to achieve this type of effect which is why psuedo elements feel ok.

Comment: ended up doing something like this... I used a border-top (yellow) to "push" the ul li ul down and now it appears as if the subnav is coming up from behind the yellow bg onto the green bg. Thanks for the assistance on this! http://jsfiddle.net/G4dss/13/

Comment: @ClaytonDaniels no problem, i suggested the psuedo element because you can have it transparent.

Answer (score 1):

This is because there is a gap between the Item 3 item, and the `<ul>` that contains the submenu items. Your `top` value specified for the submenu is too great, causing it to appear too low and create this gap. When the cursor enters this gap, the menu disappears, because the `:hover` styles are no longer applied.

One way to fix this is to use a percentage value for `top`, which takes away the guesswork of figuring out just how many pixels you need to specify for it:

```
ul li ul {
    top: 100%;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G4dss/5/) to demonstrate. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

**EDIT:** The above CSS causes the submenu `<ul>` to appear directly below the end of the bottom of the parent menu item. However, you cannot specify a value greater than 100%, otherwise the same problem will occur and the submenu will appear too low (the gap returns).

One way to address this need is to actually increase the height of the parent menu item. In your case, just make it as high as the yellow background, and the submenu will appear within the green background. So, using this CSS should work in your situation:

```
#bg > .menu > li{
    height: 70px; /* Same height as yellow #bg element */
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

This causes only the main menu items to increase in height (this way all the submenu items won't be too spaced out by increased height too). The `box-sizing` attribute is to ensure that existing padding on the `<li>` elements gets factored into the height as well, so the submenu won't appear excessively low. Here's a [new JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G4dss/12/) to demonstrate. Hope this was helpful!

Comment: OK, what if the designer sent the PSD and wanted the sub-navigation to popup from behind the yellow background (onto the green background)? The percentage doesn't seem to work here, the sub menu keeps disappearing when I mouse out... http://jsfiddle.net/G4dss/7/

Comment: If you specify a percentage exceeding 100%, the same problem will occur - because the submenu `<ul>` will once again appear below where the menu item ends, creating a gap. I'll edit my question for the new concern you raise.

Answer (score 0):

This happend because you use `top: 50px`. Change to this:

```
ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  left: 0;
  /*top: 50px; remove this*/
  padding-top:10px; /*Add this*/
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G4dss/4/)