# How to customize dropdown background-color while hover zurb-foundation 5

Tags: css, html, zurb-foundation-5

How can I customize background-color while hovering `<a href="#">Find Me</a>`.
I want to change the background-color while I'm hovering.
this's the picture before I do hovering.

[image]

and this's the picture after I do hovering

[image]

I want to customize background-color at " Find Me "
what should I add to customize background color.

and this's my code

```
<nav style="width: 1000px; margin: auto;" class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
    <ul style="margin-right: 80px;" class="title-area">
        <li class="name">
            <h1><a href="#">My Site</a></h1>
        </li>
        <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
    </ul>

    <section class="top-bar-section">
        <!-- Left Nav Section -->
        <ul class="left">
            <li class="has-dropdown">
                <a href="#">Find Me</a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Steamcommunity</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the CSS you're looking for is: `.top-bar-section li:not(.has-form) a:not(.button):hover`

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pixelsmith/dbmxds5a/) (make sure the screen is wide enough to see the second link).

You can always use your developer tools to inspect the element, and then [modify it to see the pseudo-class states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515124/see-hover-state-in-chrome-developer-tools).

I'd also recommend learning how to modify the globals in your Foundation set up as it can save you a lot of time rather than always overwriting the Foundation standards.