# Where did psuedo elements in Chrome Inspector go?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I cannot seem to find the little dotted box in my **Chrome** properties inspector that let me see psuedo elements like `:hover`, `:active`, `:focus`, `:visited`

Here is a link to what I see:
[image: Chrome Dev Tool]

Instead there is a new little animations icon there. Yay for that, it sounds handy, but I would like the dotted box back, please.

I can right click on an element and "*Force element state*" to change the psuedo class, but this method is slower. I like the old way.

I've been looking all over the place, for example this link shows the old way: [See :hover state in Chrome Developer Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515124/see-hover-state-in-chrome-developer-tools)
I even looked in Chrome's change log and at their developer site instructions (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) but no love!

Thanks guys,
-B

Answer (score 0):

for anyone else it appears that the middle icon in the image above, the pushpin icon, now replaces the dotted box. Pressing on the pushpin brings up the same controls as before.