# Disable :hover state in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, hover, google-chrome-devtools

I am aware you can force the `:hover` state on an element from the Dev Tools (see eg: [See :hover state in Chrome Developer Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515124/see-hover-state-in-chrome-developer-tools)).

I am looking to do the opposite: ***preventing* an element from having the `:hover` state applied** even though the cursor is over it.

That way I could use the element picker on elements that disappear on hover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Disable styles individually while `:hover` is in pinned state

1. Because you want to use the element picker on elements that disappear on hover, you will need to open Chrome Developer tools and manually navigate the DOM tree to the target element node.
   [image]
2. With the element selected, click the "Toggle Element State" pin icon at the top of the styles panel.
   [image]
3. Pin the `:hover` state. See that the selector and rules that define the `:hover` state now appear.
   [image]
4. Disable individual rules as needed to achieve your goal.
   [image]
5. Unpin the `:hover` state.
   [image]

You have now disabled *some or all of* the rules applied to your element's `:hover` state. You can selectively turn these back on by following the steps above and enabling *some or all of* the rules.

Comment: Quite cumbersome :-/ There should be a built-in way... But thanks for the tip!

Comment: This *is* the built-in way, so to speak. Chrome just doesn't make any assumptions about which styles you want to disable, so it let's you selectively disable them. But, there is no built-in way,per se, to turn them all off or on *at once*.

Comment: An alternative solution that you may like is to apply `pointer-events: none` to the target element's rule in the developer tools. This would preclude any `:hover` events from being invoked and it gets the job done *at once*.

Comment: ooh that's highly interesting! you should make a separate answer for that solution

Answer (score 3):

### Apply `pointer-events: none` to the target element

1. Because you want to use the element picker on elements that disappear on hover, you will need to open Chrome Developer tools and manually navigate the DOM tree to the target element node.
   [image: Open Chrome Developer tools and manually navigate the DOM tree to the target element node]
2. With the element selected, from the styles panel click somewhere near the closing bracket of the target rule to insert a new property. I recommend using the `element.style` rule to achieve the greatest specificity.
   [image]
3. A text input will appear. Enter `pointer-events: none;`.
   [image]
   [image]
4. You may now toggle this property by disabling/enabling it as normal.
   [image]

While enabled, this precludes the invocation of any `:hover` rules applied to the target element.

*Caveat: Because hover events are suppressed, the closest you'll be able to get with the element picker is the target element's parent.*