# All hovering effects on my site have stopped working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have done about 11 straight hours work on my site, adding tones of new features to it. However, I have just noticed that none of my hover effects are now working.

My site is very large and I understand that i can't post the whole thing in this, however is there any common things that may cause such a bug?

Im using bootstrap.

Comment: you must have something else overwriting the hovers

Comment: Choose some element that doesnt work and check it in devtools styles tab -> [hover state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515124/see-hover-state-in-chrome-developer-tools) see what is overriding the hover css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I would definitely suggest doing is making sure the closing curly braces all match up to the correct opening braces. That can usually cause trouble if they are not properly closed. In addition, I would suggest checking your class names in your HTML to make sure that everything is spelled properly.

Answer (score 0):

Search for a :hover in your CSS files... Or maybe you added bootstrap.css the overrides it...

Answer (score 0):

You may have accidentally removed or left out a closing bracket in your CSS. Maybe run your stylesheet through a validator to be certain - https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/