# one css property being executed without the other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am sure there is a very simple explanation for this but I have tried everything I can and seem to be missing it.  I have the following css code which is applied to li items under a ul parent.  I have applied by doing

```css
.test {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: #d9edf7;
}
.test:hover {
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="test">test</li>
  <li class="test">test2</li>
  <li class="test">test3</li>
</ul>
```

The issue is that on hover, it changes the font size without changing the background.  Am I missing something?

Comment: That code is working per your description.

Comment: It works in the snippet

Comment: As others have stated, the code you posted (which I inserted into a snippet) seems to work fine. Do you have other CSS rules (that you didn't post) that might be causing the issue?

Comment: use chrome developer tools to inspect the css properties on :hover to check for any inheritance problems. [How to do this?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6778547/3101532)

Comment: When you create a [MCVE], you need to make sure that it really is *complete*.

Comment: I used chrome developer as you advised and it shows it with a line through the background color, so I will investigate into inheritance problems as you say.

Comment: You got `!important` set by any chance?

Comment: If you want you can load all your code into http://jsfiddle.net so we can see it not working. You'll need to give us the link of course.

Comment: i just inserted !important and that didnt do the job.  I even tested by putting the specific rule in a style tag within the html.  I will just have to fiddle around until I get something

Comment: I am dealing with bootstrap, it turned out the   .nav>li>a:hover rule was overriding me and i just changed my rule to .nav>li.test>a:hover.  This way it changes the background on just .test classes instead of all nav's going forward

Comment: It works in firefox, what browser are you using?

Comment: @user3352112 Read up on specificity. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity