# Upon hovering link, css declaration doesn't work

Tags: css, hover

I have this navigation links and upon hovering the last link (styled as button), I want it to have a property of bottom border of color pink instead of brown upon hover to complement the color red button. Your help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
.header-nav a:hover {
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(56,47,50); /*brown border-bottom*/
}

.header-nav a:last-of-type:hover {
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(255,144,171); /*pink-border-bottom*/
} 

        <nav class="container header-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#cupcakes">Cupcakes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#cakes">Cakes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#events">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contacts" class="btn nav-btn">Order Now!</a></li>
            </ul>
            <br>
        </nav>
```

Here's the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ssqLspsn/

Comment: This css is ok. Please show your html

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jbw5qdef/ You might have some conflicts in css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i DID IT!!! https://jsfiddle.net/Please_Reply/9hk6okpd/2/ hope this is what you want!!!

```
.header-nav a:hover {
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(56,47,50); /*brown border-bottom*/
}

.header-nav .btn:hover {
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(255,144,171); /*pink-border-bottom*/
}
```

Comment: Yay! Good luck! Please accept my answer by clicking the tick and also feel free to ask me anymore questions @Ly18

Comment: Thanks @nobodyshere

Comment: You're welcome!!! @Ly18 : Remember feel free to tag me in the future if you need my help to try and answer a question :)

Answer (score 1):

I DID IT!!! Look here https://jsfiddle.net/Please_Reply/9hk6okpd/2/ hope this is what you want!!!

```
.header-nav a:hover {
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(56,47,50); /*brown border-bottom*/
}

.header-nav .btn:hover {
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(255,144,171); /*pink-border-bottom*/
}
```

Comment: sorry, but it doesn't work. It only applied the border bottom in the whole list item not in the specified a element

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand what you are asking for? I would like to help so please upload pictures or provide a JSFiddle

Comment: Actually could you please provide us with some code. Edit any personal details out first if you would like.

Comment: @Ly18 sorry I forgot to tag you

Comment: .header-nav .li:last-child a:hover is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Try to put some class to the button (last element)
You css is fine although

like

```
<div class="header-nav">
<a>some text</a>
<a>some text</a>
<a class="btn">some text</a>
</div>
```

css

```
header-nav .btn:hover {
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(255,144,171); /*pink-border-bottom*/
}
```

If you want to keep your css selectors, you should select on `li`, not `a`
Raplace `.header-nav a:last-of-type:hover` with `.header-nav .li:last-child a:hover`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you will put id or class name for last li and make css code the specific id :)

Comment: i did that already but it doesn't work (same property being applied). specificity sucks. kidding! just a newbie here.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do when checking which css is applied on hover is to have the hover attribute active from the console. 
You can do this both in firefox and chrome by going to the inspector.
Here is the guide to seeing how to activate the hover attribute
[See :hover state in Chrome Developer Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515124/see-hover-state-in-chrome-developer-tools)

As for your specific problem it would help if you also posted your html, because css will not work if you're applying the style to a wrong element.

```
.header-nav li:hover {
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(56,47,50); /*brown border-bottom*/
}

.header-nav li:last-of-type:hover {
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(255,144,171); /*pink-border-bottom*/
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: hi there! here's the html snippet:
   <nav class="container header-nav">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#cupcakes">Cupcakes</a></li>
     <li><a href="#cakes">Cakes</a></li>
     <li><a href="#events">Events</a></li>
     <li><a href="#contacts" class="btn nav-btn">Order Now!</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br>
   </nav>

thanks, btw!