# How do browser devtools simulate :hover, :focus and :active states?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I'm building something to show elements in these different states and it's making me curious.

Is there some simple way to trigger these?

Are they rewriting the selectors / classlists under the hood? This can work but you'd need to do it for every child as well and seems really error prone and messy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [See :hover state in Chrome Developer Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515124/see-hover-state-in-chrome-developer-tools)  ------------ ***Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27623294/11171286***

Comment: No. I'm asking how devtools simulates the `:hover` state in the CSS. That answer simulates the event to get the JS event to happen.

Comment: The more I read around the less I feel like it's possible. It seems like everyone else trying to accomplish this needs to rewrite this styles.

Comment: Devtools is using the internal CDP command [CSS.forcePseudoState](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/CSS/#method-forcePseudoState). You can inspect the [source code](https://source.chromium.org/chromium).

Comment: Thank you wOxxOm! The exact answer I was looking for. I’ll read up on this a bit.