# Can not find CSS causing issue of text links moving and decorating themselves

Tags: html, css, formatting

If you check out this site https://cleetus.youtubersblog.com/our-ls-swapped-blazer-returns-will-this-be-too-much-nitrous-major-upgrades/ you will notice that the menu on the right under Recent Posts, if you hover your mouse over the link it will shift its position and when you click it, it will underline and 'overline??' itself, I am pretty knowledgeable in CSS yet I can not find where this behavior is coming from. Of course I am right clicking and looking at the 'inspect' and yet, it eludes me... can anyone help?

Comment: May be  you added `text-indent` on `hover` . It is adviced to share the code needed to reproduce your problem , Not just link to website , this is a helping platform not a debugging service.

Comment: Thanks @Rana I looked for hover in the CSS and found nothing that helped, normally when you 'inspect' you see everything that related to that element, but this time.... nope! Thanks again.

Comment: `.mg-sidebar .mg-widget ul li a:hover {padding-left: 10px ;transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;}` . This is what that makes your content move on `hover`

Comment: Keep the advice in mind from next time . As it is your first question but next time provide some code (`html` `CSS`) to reproduce the problem . Else these type of question are closed and downvoted by the community.

Comment: Rana, thanks, so when I look under 'inspect' and Styles I do not see this for that element, I see things close to this and when I uncheck them nothing changes, do you have any lessons for finding such CSS entries in this case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6778547/16846346 : See this answer to know style of hover state in inspect .

Comment: gotcha! so cool... figured it out, force state :-) I google and get answers 100x a day, I VERY rarely bug for answers, just sometimes like this after a week and getting no where... again! thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by force state and what is the solution you found

Comment: I think you solved it out as it is not visible on your site . This way this question remains no way useful for future readers , as they can't see the problem . That's the reason of providing code here

Comment: First thing I did was right click on the link in Chrome and pick 'Inspect', then in the inspection window in the Elements tab I right click on the <a></a> that we are trying to diagnose and right click on that and pick 'force state' and then ':hover'. Only then will the CSS show up in the 'Styles' tab that allows you then to tweak and play with it to correct the behavior that was annoying. I was not doing the 'force state' step before and thus the CSS was not showing.....