# button class with :focus does not show outline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show that buttons have focus, especially when accessed by keyboard. I can tab to the buttons and Developer Tools shows that the button has focus. But, no outline appears. Hovering over the buttons does show the outline *except* when it has focus.

```css
.remove_input_button:focus {
  outline: 2px solid black;
}

.remove_input_button:hover:not(:disabled) {
  outline: 2px solid black;
}


/* Bootstrap CSS */

button:focus:not(:focus-visible) {
  outline: 0;
}

.btn:focus,
.btn.focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary remove_input_button" type="button">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="delete">
    </button>
```

I have also tried `:focus-visible`, without success. Developer Tools does not show any `:focus` or `:hover` styles so I cannot determine whether the Bootstrap styles are affecting my application. I expected my CSS to have priority. Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Developer tools does provide the ability to debug `:focus` and `:hover` styles. Here's how it works in Chrome: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515124/see-hover-state-in-chrome-developer-tools

Answer (score 0):

I removed some code. It was probably intended to affect other controls.

```
.btn:focus {
    outline: 0 !important;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

I used this style. The outline is only needed when focus is gained from the keyboard.

```
.remove_input_button:focus-visible {
    outline: 2px solid black;
}
```